# Multiple window frames generated from one java program

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jframe

I am currently writing a Java implementation of Catan. Is there way to run the program and then have it generate a different frame for each player of the game. It's alright if all the frames are on the same machine (I plan on using a split monitor display). Should I look into JFrame for this? I don't have much experience with it so I'm not sure if it can do this or how it easy it is.

Comment: *"Should I look into JFrame for this?"*  Yes.  Be sure to specify the close operations as `JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE` as seen in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7143287/how-to-best-position-swing-guis/7143398#7143398).

Comment: Thanks. Also, just to be sure, is there a way to take different input from the two frames, as in having a different `System.in` stream running in each?

Comment: *"is there a way to take different input from the two frames"*  Yes. *"as in having a different `System.in` stream"* Start each in a new `Process` if you want 2 x `System.in`, but it should not really be necessary.